# Fill in HTML fields through URL

Tags: html, url

I have multiple external websites where a single username must be filled in for each page. I am trying to make everything easier by combining all these fields into one single username input. Clicking the submit button after typing in the username will open the external websites in new tabs each with the username already filled in. I was planning on doing this through the URLs. For example

```
   http://www.website.com/vote?username=inputted_username
```

The problem is that this method does not work for 4 out of the 5 external websites. When I use it, the website loads up without the field being filled in. Is there another way to do this without having to download loads of Javascript libraries and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

The external website must implement the corresponding code to accept setting fields through URLs, and if it doesn't you **can't** do anything, even with javascript, since accessing elements of an external domain is considered a security issue and banned by almost-all browsers. So you should kindly ask those websites to support filling the fields through URL parameters.

Comment: I'm looking at the HTML code for the website right now. Is there a way to determine whether or not the website accepts inputs through URL?

Comment: Not generally. You should have access to read/change the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

If your able to use PHP you could do this:

```
<?php $username = $_GET['username']; ?>

 <input value="<?php echo $username; ?>"></input>
```

It will GET the username from the URL and output the username at the echo

Comment: That will help with posting the URL values but the thing is that these websites are external so the only way I am able to interact with the HTML fields is through the URL. I'm not familiar with PHP but is there a way to output the username on an external site completely unrelated to mine?

Comment: How exactly is the external site receiving data?

Comment: I'm not too sure on it either. Here, letme give you the site: www.planetminecraft.com/server/omega-realm-146/vote. I am trying to pass on the username to the field called 'mcname' but it doesn't do anything when I try it.

Comment: That site you gave me, do you run it or does someone else run it? Also is this a CMS ran site or is it custom by you?

Comment: @Ruijikin I don't run the site. Is there any way to input the username into that one field? It seems as if the site were receiving the field like any other would.

Comment: If you don't run the site then you cannot change it. If they provided a method for you to do such a thing then it would be possible to send it through the URL. If not then there is no way to do it.